# method to search through all controls and only picking out a certain type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am looking for a methods that can loop through all the controls on my page and only pick out certain types.  In this case, I am only looking for the html element textarea.

I have this loop...

```
For Each control As HtmlTextArea In myDiv.Controls.Cast(Of HtmlTextArea)()

    If TypeOf Control Is HtmlTextArea Then
        ...do something...
    End If

Next
```

But it always fails when it reaches a control other than an HtmlTextArea saying that it is unable to cast said control to HtmlTextArea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `OfType` instead of `Cast`.

```
For Each control As HtmlTextArea In myDiv.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlTextArea)()

    'If is no longer needed, control will be HtmlTextArea
    ...do something...

Next
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) for OfType

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a delegate to the end, if you want to single out controls with a certain attribute.  In this case, it only looks at the visible HtmlTextAreas:

```
For Each control As HtmlTextArea In myDiv.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlTextArea)().Where(Function(textArea) textArea.Visible = True)

        'Do stuff here
        control.InnerHtml = "I am visible"

Next control
```